# R: Split column of data into multiple, based on nr. of characters

Tags: r, split

I have this column of data:

```
variable
WinterMACV
WinterMACV
WinterMACV
WinterMACV
WinterMACV
WinterMACV
...
```

I want to split it in 3: "Winter", "M" and "ACV". So it has to split after 6 letters, then 1, and the last 3 remain.

I've found info about splitting at a certain character like "_", "," of " ". But how about after a certain nr of characters?
I was planning to use `str_split_fixed()` from the `stringr` package. Don't know if that's possible here.

Comment: Something like `strsplit(sub("^(.{6})(.)(.{3})$","\\1;\\2;\\3",string),";")` (`string` is your vector of strings) might work, but might not depending on the possible values that the string might contain. Here I added a `;` after six and seven characters and then split by `;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know for sure that the string you are splitting will always have the characters in those positions then:

```
df %>% mutate(v1 = substr(variable, 1, 6),
              v2 = substr(variable, 7, 7),
              v3 = substr(variable, 8, 10))
```

Comment: This works, thank you. Had to add the dataset name before v1 though.
Also used df <- mutate(). I'm not familiar with %>% and R gave an error.